# Does liquid aerification work?

Tags: lawn

I have terrible soil in my yard, because the builder scraped off most of the topsoil and sold it.  I need to aerate the yard and get some more nutrients in it.  Has anyone tried any  of the liquid aerification products?  I tried Aerify Plus, but it hasn't been long enough to judge if it is helping.

Comment: If you can, let us know how the liquid aerification works out.  I have clay soil and struggle with compaction, and I'm sure others would like to know as well.

Comment: I have applied the product three times per instructions, but I have not seen a lot of difference.  The experiment will probably end in the fall when I do mechanical aeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The liquid aeration didn't appear to do much.  Part of it is the moderate drought my area of the country is in.  I am going to have the lawn mechanically aerated in a couple of weeks, so the experiment is over.

Answer (score 2):

Liquid aerification doesn't really sound like a good idea to me, but I quite honestly know nothing about it.

What I'd do: Rent an aerator, spread compost and/or some good fertilizer, and water the yard. Repeat at least once a year. If you don't have any grass growing currently, bring in some compost and mix it in with the existing soil with a tiller (or something bigger).

Comment: I agree this is the proper process to do this, but it is something that is typically only done in the fall.  It is also a lot of work and costs a lot of money.

Comment: You can also do this in spring. You just want to avoid the really long stretches of high heat in the summer.

Comment: Bringing in compost is what will cost you the most (and is the most optional part of the process!). Renting an aerator isn't that bad, especially if you get your neighbors interested in it, too.

But yeah, don't do it during the heat of the summer. Unless you're trying to kill the lawn. :-)

Comment: Talk to any of the local farms with livestock near you.  There's plenty of horse farms near me that are glad to give away composted manure if you pick it up.  For lawns use, and not vegetable gardens, I'd assume you don't need to worry so much if it hit the proper temperatures.

Answer (score 0):

A popular form of compost that is easy to apply is alfalfa compost.  It comes in pellets that you can spread with any typical lawn spreader for fertilizer.  Avoid using commercial fertilizers as they become like drugs for your lawn - the lawn will not grow without the fertilizer.

Build up the lawn with compost, mulched leaves in the fall and mulched clippings.  You may have to add some topsoil back into your lawn, but keep in mind that sellers are allowed to sell topsoil full of weed seeds.  If you add some topsoil to your lawn, the next year you may find your lawn is full of weeds!